# Use Alias Columns to calculate another Alias Column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT SomeData.., Order.EurAmount AS OrderTotalEeur, 
--Begin Subselect
(SELECT Sum(Invoice.EurAmount) 
FROM Invoice WHERE Invoice.OrderId = Order.Id 
GROUP BY Invoice.OrderId) As InvoiceTotalEur
--End Subselect
([Order].EurAmount - IIF(InvoiceTotalEur is null, 0, InvoiceTotalEur) AS Diff
FROM [Order]
```

As you can see I want to get 2 Amounts (OrderTotalEur and InvoiceTotalEur), no big deal. But I also want to use these two aliases to calculate another column (Diff) which does not work, because it does not recognize the two aliases for calculating the diff column.

What I can do is repeat the Subselect two more times (For the iif and for the value) but this can't be the right way, correct?

Comment: Your syntax looks like SQL Server or MS Access.  Why is the question tagged "plsql"?

Comment: My bad! Fixed it. Its SQL Server. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add consider your query as a subquery:

```
  SELECT SomeData..,  
    OrderTotalEeur,
    InvoiceTotalEur,
    (OrderTotalEeur - IIF(InvoiceTotalEur is null, 0, InvoiceTotalEur) AS Diff
  FROM (
      SELECT SomeData.., Order.EurAmount AS OrderTotalEeur, 
      --Begin Subselect
      (SELECT Sum(Invoice.EurAmount) 
      FROM Invoice WHERE Invoice.OrderId = Order.Id 
       GROUP BY Invoice.OrderId) As InvoiceTotalEur
      --End Subselect
    FROM [Order]
    ) myquery
```

then in the upper level you can access the alias.